# How to pass private key as text to ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm using one service which is connected to remote host via ssh. I don't  want to store or write ssh keys on that service, I want pass keys to service  and execute `ssh` connection to another host using passed keys before.

To connect to host I used: `ssh user@host -i /path/to/key`.

How can I use key as the `text` not a specific file?
I tried `ssh user@host -i "key-text-example"`. It doesn't  work like that.

Comment: it works like that; but key must have 400 rights

Comment: The bash tag was ok.

Comment: That said, if the OP's actual goal is to have a "bounce host" that they SSH through without storing their private key there, it sounds like what they *really* need is agent forwarding. If the host they're SSH'ing through has been 0wned, the mechanism here won't prevent the attacker from capturing the private key (it'll show up plain as day in a [sysdig](https://sysdig.org/) trace, for example).

Comment: @Drako , sorry but  400 rights for what?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: right for that key file should be 400

Comment: @Drako with key file works just fine, it doesn't work with key as text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as a literal answer to your question, but as the best way to meet your actual need (of connecting via SSH to a remote machine via a system you don't trust to store your private key) -- you should use SSH agent forwarding.

When you pass your private key to a remote system, even transiently, it can be captured; if an attacker is recording everything that goes on on the system with [Sysdig](https://sysdig.org/), for example, the writes over the FIFO from the process substitution (or the reads done by the SSH client process) will show up plain as day.

Instead of passing the private key to the remote system, agent forwarding sends the request for a signature back from the remote system to your origin machine. (There are even SSH agents for Android, so you can have the request forwarded to your phone -- presumably a device you trust -- such that the private key never leaves it). Similarly, a hardware device such as a YubiKey can store your private key and perform signature operations on behalf of a SSH client -- on behalf of a remote machine when agent forwarding is requested.

For the simple case:

```
local$ [[ $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ]] || eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
local$ ssh-add  # load the key into your local agent
local$ ssh -A host1  # connects to host1 with agent forwarding enabled
host1$ ssh host2     # asks the ssh agent on "local" to authenticate to host2
host2$
```